# Help me with this limit

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{x\to0} {{xe^x \over e^x-1}-1 \over x}$$

I know it should equal  ${1 \over 2}$ because when i calculate with number like $0.0001$ the limit $\approx {1 \over 2}$   but i can't prove it.

Comment: what are you allowed to use? Expand $e^x$ in Maclaurin series up to $O(x^2)$ for $x \to 0$. What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

First multiply numerator and denominator by $e^x-1$ to rewrite the fraction as

$$\frac{xe^x - e^x + 1}{xe^x-x}$$

**Solution 1:**

Now we apply [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) twice to see

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{xe^x - e^x + 1}{xe^x-x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{xe^x}{e^x+xe^x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+xe^x}{2e^x+xe^x}=\frac{1}{2}$$

**Solution 2:** (without L'Hôpital's rule)

Remember that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$. That is, we have $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^3)$ close to $0$. Therefore

$$\frac{xe^x - e^x + 1}{xe^x-x}=\frac{(1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^3))(x-1)+1}{x(x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^3))}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^3)}{x^2+O(x^3)}=\frac{1+O(x)}{2+O(x)}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}$$

as $x\rightarrow 0$.

In case you're not familiar with the $O$-notation:

$O(x^n)$ is just a placeholder for some function $f$ such there exists some $C>0$ and $x_0>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le C|x^n|$ for all $x$ with $|x|\le x_0$, i.e. $O(x^n)$ means asymptotic growth at most like $x^n$ near $0$.

Comment: Thank you but i can't use L'Hôpital's rule

Comment: @user115947: Why not?

Comment: Because my school program doesn't entitle me to use it

Comment: I never studied L'Hôpital's rule

Comment: @user115947: I gave you the link. Look it up on wikipedia and understand it. It's worth it. Alternatively look at the second version which is the same proof just doing what L'Hôpital does "by hand".

Answer (score 1):

Divide the top and bottom by $x$ to clean stuff up:

$$\dots={ {{e^x \over e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x} }}\normalsize=\frac{x\cdot e^x-e^x+1}{x\cdot(e^x-1)}$$

Can you do it now?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I there, what you do is use [L'Hosptial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) several times:

Your limit is a limit of the type $\frac{0}{0}$. Using L'Hospital yields:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\ldots) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\exp(2x)-\exp(x)-x\exp(x)}{(\exp(x)-1)^2}$$
Then using L'Hospital twice more (in each case you will still have limit of the type $\frac{0}{0}$) yields:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\ldots) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{4\exp{2x}-3\exp(x)-x\exp(x)}{2\exp{x}}$$
And using $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \exp(x) = 1$ then yiels the result of $\frac{1}{2}$ you were looking for!
Hope that helps :).

I'm reading above you can for some reason not use L'Hospital. Alternatively
you can use the Taylor expansion for the exponential function:
$$\exp(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots$$
Then after rearranging the expression as the smart people above me did:
$$\frac{x\exp(x)-\exp(x)+1}{x\exp(x)-x} = \frac{x+x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^2) - 1 - x - 0.5\cdot x^2 \mathcal{O}(x^2) + 1}{x+x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^2)-x}$$
Rearranging gives:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\ldots) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{x^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^2)}{x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^2)} = \frac{1}{2}$$